# Update filter and DataGrid on any change in any textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 4 TextBoxes. I use each of them as a filter parameter for DataGrid. The problem is that I have to cover all the possible variants with IF function in order to get them working correctly. Is there any better way of doing this?

Below is one example that is not covering even all variants. I also need to modify it for each texbox sepately.

Here is the code:

```
    private void BusinessIDSearch_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        _conditions["name"] = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(BusinessIDSearch.Text))
        {
            _conditions["name"] = string.Format("LY Like '{0}%'", BusinessIDSearch.Text);
            UpdateFilter();
            FICount.Content = DataGrid1.Items.Count;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NameSearch.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(BusinessIDSearch.Text))
        {
            _conditions["name"] = string.Format("HAKUNIMI Like '%{0}%' AND LY Like '%{1}%'", NameSearch.Text, BusinessIDSearch.Text);
            UpdateFilter();
            FICount.Content = DataGrid1.Items.Count;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NameSearch.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(GroupSearch.Text))
        {
            _conditions["name"] = string.Format("HAKUNIMI Like '%{0}%' AND KONSERNI Like '%{1}%' AND YRNRO Like '{2}%'", NameSearch.Text, GroupSearch.Text, IDSearch.Text);
            UpdateFilter();
            FICount.Content = DataGrid1.Items.Count;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(BusinessIDSearch.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(GroupSearch.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(NameSearch.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(IDSearch.Text))
        {
            _conditions["name"] = string.Format("HAKUNIMI Like '%{0}%' AND KONSERNI Like '%{1}%' AND YRNRO Like '{2}%' AND LY Like '{3}%'", NameSearch.Text, GroupSearch.Text, IDSearch.Text, BusinessIDSearch.Text);
            UpdateFilter();
            FICount.Content = DataGrid1.Items.Count;
        }
    }
```

---

**UPDATE:**

This application is to be used on certain local computers only, so there shouldn't be SQL injection risks. However I know that this is not the best "coding".

Comment: 1) WPF and MVVM: use bindings instead events and in property setters call `UpdateFilter()` method of *view model*. 2) You can create filter dynamically: `X Like ...` = string.Join + " AND " separator. For working code consider to use [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) next time.

Comment: Add the relevant conditions to a list, then `condition = string.Join(" AND ", list);`. This way you don't have to write all possible condition combinations by hand.

Comment: @grek40 can you provide an example in answer just for others might be founding this in the future?

Comment: @hatman, "...there shouldn't be SQL injection risks" is a dangerous way of thinking. Your code lives beyond you - someone *will* use it elsewhere and/or your application will be exposed to others outside of your company. Also, someone within your company can decide to "play." I *always* code for SQL injection and other vulnerabilities.

Comment: @n8wrl This is true! I will rewrite everything before it gets to others hands in a proper way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

The idea is to check each of your parameters in turn and build up your query string. Also note that you shouldn't blindly pass user-entered text to a database - you need to guard against SQL injection.

```
    string qry = null;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(BusinessIDSearch.Text))
    {
        qry = string.Format("LY Like '{0}%'", DeInjectText(BusinessIDSearch.Text));
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NameSearch.Text))
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(qry))
            qry += " AND ";
        qry += string.Format("HAKUNIMI Like '%{0}%'", DeInjectText(NameSearch.Text));
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(GroupSearch.Text))
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(qry))
            qry += " AND ";
        qry += string.Format("KONSERNI Like '%{0}%'", DeInjectText(GroupSearch.Text));
    }
    ....
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(qry))
    {
        UpdateFilter();
        FICount.Content = DataGrid1.Items.Count;
    }

public string DeInjectText(text)
{
    // Do stuff here to remove SQL injection danger from text
    return text;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I got an idea, however DeInjectText seem to give an error although it looks correct. I am just wondering what I am making wrong

Comment: @hatman need more info on your DeInjectText error. Keep in mind my function example does nothing - you need to decide what makes sense for you, and perhaps this is a more global function in your project. You'll want to filter out various character combinations, like begin-comments, end-quotes, etc. Google for more